Upgrading to React 19 - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ReactCurrentOwner')
Looking to upgrade a web application to React 19 RC to try out some of its features and mitigate breaking changes ahead of time.
I tried following the steps laid out here: https://react.dev/blog/2024/04/25/react-19-upgrade-guide but upon building the application, I get an error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ReactCurrentOwner')
    at Object.251 (/path/to/project/node_modules/react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.min.js:2:1444)
    at i (/path/to/project/node_modules/react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.min.js:2:2018)
    at Object.893 (/path/to/project/node_modules/react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.min.js:2:1892)
    at i (/path/to/project/node_modules/react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.min.js:2:2018)
    at /path/to/project/node_modules/react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.min.js:2:2631
    at /path/to/project/node_modules/react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.min.js:2:20482
    at /path/to/project/node_modules/react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.min.js:2:20488
    at /path/to/project/node_modules/react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.min.js:2:81
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/project/node_modules/react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.min.js:2:245)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)

Node.js v18.17.1

Has anybody seen this before?
I ran npm install react@rc react-dom@rc and then manually included the following in my package.json:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "npm:types-react@rc",
    "@types/react-dom": "npm:types-react-dom@rc"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "@types/react": "npm:types-react@rc",
    "@types/react-dom": "npm:types-react-dom@rc"
  }
}

